# JavaScript: implement let-working with var

Tags: javascript, var, let

So I have a code that clone let-behavior. But I don't undestand how and why it is working. Can someone explain it?

```
(function() {
  var a = 2;
})()
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: I don't understand the question. `let` and `var` are almost equivalent when they're at the top level of a function definition.

Comment: @Barmar - I think the point is that the equivalent with `let` would just be in a block (but it would improve the question markedly to show *what* the OP is trying to clone).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, it makes sense now. I'm usually the one who's good at decoding poor questions like this :)

Comment: @Barmar - You are indeed. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`let` is scoped to the block it appears in.

`var` is scoped to the function it appears in.

By replacing a block with a function (which is immediately invoked) `var` is scoped to the same lines of code as `let` would be.

Answer (score 3):

Where you can only use `var` variables but you want to ensure that a variable declaration is not going to overwrite another pre-existing variable of the same name, you can use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to scope that variable to the function. This in effect creates a "block", similar to the second example below.

`var` variables are scoped to functions:

```js
var a = 1;
let b = 1;

(function() {
  var a = 2;
  let b = 1;
})();

console.log(a); //=> 1 (a is not overwritten because the second `var a` is function-scoped)
console.log(b); //=> 1
```

`let` variables are scoped to blocks:

```js
let a = 1;
var b = 1;

{
  let a = 2;
  var b = 2;
}

console.log(a); //=> 1 (a is not overwritten as let is block-scoped)
console.log(b); //=> 2 (b is overwritten as var is not block-scoped)
```

It's worth mentioning that you can redeclare a `var` variable, hence why it would be possible to overwrite an existing `var` variable of the same name. However, you cannot redeclare a `let` variable:

```js
var a = 1

// will not error as `var` does not prevent redeclaration
var a = 2

let b = 1

{
  // will not error as `b` is not declared in this block
  let b = 2
}

// will error as `b` is already declared in this scope
let b = 3
```

You can read more about `let` and `var` in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var?rq=1).